# Eloquent join with scopes having ambiguous column names

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, left-join

I've got two tables, `venues` and `venue_plans`, having a `hasOne` relationship. The former contains geolocation data, while the latter contains a "distance bonus", so the more the distance bonus, the closer the venue will be shown to the user who's searching around its location.

There's also a third table, `categories`, which has a `hasMany` relationship. Basically, each venue can have more than one categories set, as simple as that.

I have managed to add to scopes: the first one calculates the distance from a given location (for example, the user location), calculates the distance bonus and sort the venues by both fields:

```
public function scopeWithDistanceFrom($query, $lat, $lng, $units = 'km') {
    $units = ($units === "km") ? 6378.10 : 3963.17;
    $lat = (float) $lat;
    $lng = (float) $lng;
    $lat_column = 'geo_latitude';
    $lng_column = 'geo_longitude';

    // Join with venue_plans to get the distance bonus
    $query->leftJoin('venue_plans', 'venues.id', 'venue_plans.venue_id');

    // Add distance column
    $distance_raw = "$units * ACOS(
                        COS(RADIANS($lat)) * COS(RADIANS($lat_column))
                        * COS(RADIANS($lng) - RADIANS($lng_column))
                        + SIN(RADIANS($lat)) * SIN(RADIANS($lat_column))
                    ) AS distance";
    $query->selectRaw($distance_raw);

    // Add distance_bonused column
    $distance_bonused_raw = "(SELECT (distance - (distance / 100 * distance_bonus))) as distance_bonused";
    $query->selectRaw($distance_bonused_raw);

    // Sort by distance
    $query->orderBy('distance_bonused', 'desc');
    $query->orderBy('distance', 'desc');

    return $query;
}
```

The second one searches venues by their name (`venue.name`) or by the category name (`categories.name`).

```
public function scopeWithNameOrCategoryName($query, $name) {
    return $query
        ->where('name', 'like', "%{$name}%") // Venue name
        ->orWhereHas('categories', function($query) use ($name){ // Category name
            $query->where('name', 'like', "%{$name}%");
        });
}
```

While they both work fine when used separately, when I use them together, like with

```
Venue::withNameOrCategory('myname')
    ->withDistanceFrom(35.0386, 13.92)
    ->take(5)->get();
```

I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'name' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select `venues`.*, 6378.1 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(35.0386)) * COS(RADIANS(geo_latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(13.92) - RADIANS(geo_longitude)) + SIN(RADIANS(35.0386)) * SIN(RADIANS(geo_latitude))) AS distance, (SELECT (distance - (distance / 100 * distance_bonus))) as distance_bonused from `venues` left join `venue_plans` on `venues`.`id` = `venue_plans`.`venue_id` where (`name` like %myname% or exists (select * from `categories` inner join `category_venue` on `categories`.`id` = `category_venue`.`category_id` where `venues`.`id` = `category_venue`.`venue_id` and `categories`.`name` like %myname%)) order by `distance_bonused` desc, `distance` desc limit 5)
```

I should mention that even the `venue_plans` table has a `name` column, to store the selected plan name and keep it specific for that venue.

Can somebody explain to me what's the cleanest method to do this? I would also avoid to use table names and joins if possible.

Thanks

Comment: Use `->where('venues.name', 'like', "%{$name}%") // Venue name` instead in the second scope.

Comment: I thought I had tried that. It's working, thank you!